# SeekBar: change apperarance in code with drawable rectangles

Tags: android, drawable, seekbar, rectangles

I am a beginner at android, but hoping to release an app shortly.

My problem is, that I would like to have a seekbar with colored areas according to user/database input.

I have tried some things with ShapeDrawable but I am comletely lost and the only result I got was making the seekbar completely black.

I am not allowed to post images, but here is link to a photoshopped image of what I am looking for:
http://www.burninglobster.com/device-2012-10-29-155734ps.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually draw to bitmap via canvas according to your input data.

```
Bitmap.Config bmpConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(seekbar.getWidth(), seekbar.getHeight(), bmpConfig);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(this.bmp);
canvas.drawRect(...);   // draw whatever you need

seekbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bmp));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works, but the 'Drawable' was for the 'SeekBar', so I used 'seekbar.setProgressDrawable(...)'
I'm also having another issue with 'seekbar.getWidth' which is coming up 0 until first time I use the seekbar.
I also have one more question: Is it always necessary to set up a Bitmap for the canvas in order to make drawable to use for backgrounds and similar?

Comment: setProgressDrawable(...) - sure, my bad. As for zero width, View returns non-zero width after it was laid out.
If you don't want to use bitmap this way, you could create your own SeekBar class, inherited from system one, and override the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method and draw to canvas whatever you need.